# ion-nav-bar not displaying anything

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I created a navigation bar using `ionic-nav-bar`. Added an `h1` element with class `title`. But it's not displaying anything.

Here's my code

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

However, this is working:

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
 <ion-nav-title>hello</ion-nav-title>
 </ion-nav-bar>
```

This Will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ion-nav-bar will be your navigation bar and you will have ion-views that will be plugged into the ion-content section. You would never want one title if you have a nav bar because the title should change as you navigate across ion-views. When you create you ion-view tag add a view-title attribute. Then when that view is active it will automatically update the header no h1 tag required.

The ion-header approach works because ion-header is designed to be a static and not dynamically update like a navigation header would.

Comment: where should i add `ion-view` and there is no `title` attribute in the `nav-bar` tags. It's in `h1` tag

Answer (score 0):

That would be the html file of your view:

```
<ion-view title='My Title' class="dashboard"> 
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In your case you should wrap all that in an other `ion-nav-view`-element, because you are using the 
`ion-nav-bar`-element.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that your

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

tag is displayed but it is placed behind your `<ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>`. As Anand suggested in answer above you should use `<ion-nav-title>Test</ion-nav-title>` to get expected result.

Hope this helps.